# Having trouble removing entry from queue and adding it to stack

Tags: c++, list, stack, queue

UPDATE

What I am trying to accomplish is once an entry has been removed from the queue, it then gets added to a stack.  The dequeue and push functions work fine separately, but I'm not sure how to get the function to add to the stack too.  It seems to be stepping over the if statement I've created inside the queue function to push the info to the stack.

```
bool Queue::dequeue(qInfo& aInfo)
{

//Check if the queue is empty
if(isEmpty())
    return false;
else
{
    qNode* temp = front;

    //Check if this is the Only Node
    if(front == rear)
        front = rear = NULL;
    else
        front = front->next;

    temp->next = NULL;
    aInfo = temp->item;
    if(aInfo.getCoupons(true))
    {
        cout << "The code made it this far." << endl;       //Test to see if code stepped through
        char name[100];
        char email[100];
        Stack sAdd;

        cout << "The code made it this far." << endl;       //Test to see if code stepped through

        aInfo.getFname(name);
        aInfo.getEmail(email);

        sInfo newSinfo(name, email);
        sAdd.push(newSinfo);
        cout << "The code made it this far." << endl;       //Test to see if code stepped through
    }

    delete temp;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is far too much code. Please, try to reduce the code until it contains only the relevant parts concerning your problem. It might be that once you made the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you just find the error on your own. (Wouldn't be the first time.) Btw. did you try debug your problem?

Comment: Sorry, doing my research I saw that some people didn't put enough code so I wanted to make sure I did.

Comment: After editing you provide much less code but: Do you assume I can copy/paste your code and compile it on my side? The C in [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) stands for "Complete" but you may also think "Compilable". I warmly recommend to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) also. IMHO it's worth reading.

Comment: Thanks for your help in directing me toward useful material.  I'm still pretty new at ALL of this so I need all the help I can get.  I solved my issue too, by the way, just took some more time.